# RestSharp some object values being sent as null to API via PUT or POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I am sending an object from my web project to my API project within the same solution. I have a class that uses RestSharp and acts as the sender to the API for all services. 
Currently, there is one API controller that is receiving the object, but not all of the parameters are being retained and show up with null values via PUT. However, a different controller using the ApiClient's 'PutAsync' receives its own object with all the values intact. 
I've even tried changing the method to receive as a POST, but still no success. 
Am I missing something, or is there something wrong that is happening with the serialization/de-serialization of the object?

```
      public class UserInfo
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; private set; }
    }
```

```
    internal class WebService : IWebService
    {
        public async Task<bool> UpdateProfile(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
             try
             {
                 var url = "/User/UpdateProfile";
                 return await apiClient.PutAsync<UserInfo, bool>(url, userInfo);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 this.logger.LogError("Error in UpdateProfile", ex);
                 throw;
             }
         }
    }
```

**RestSharp Setup**

```
    internal class ApiClient : IApiClient
    {
        public async Task<TOut> PutAsync<TIn, TOut>(string url, TIn data) where TIn : new()
        {
            return await PushData<TIn, TOut>(url, data, Method.PUT);
        }

        private async Task<TOut> PushData<TIn, TOut>(string url, TIn data, Method method) where TIn : new()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(url, method);
            request.AddHeader(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), $"Bearer {GetApiAccessToken()}");
            request.AddJsonBody(data);
            var result = await client.ExecuteAsync<TOut>(request);
            if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to push API data");
            }

            return result.Data;
        }
    }
```

Data in the request prior to being sent out, found under the Parameters, are as followed:
[Data sent to API UserController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDng2.png)

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("UpdateProfile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile([FromBody] ProfileUpdateInfo profileInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var status = await this.service.UpdateProfile(profileInfo);

                return Ok(status);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error in updating profile");
            }
        }   
    }
```

This is the Data that shows up in the parameter:
[Data Consumed by API UserController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qwoo.png)

Comment: What's `client` in `ApiController`?

Comment: And why do you have `new()` constraint?

Comment: ```client``` is a reference to RestSharp's ```RestClient``` and the ```new()``` constraint lets the compiler know that any type argument supplied must have an accessible parameterless constructor.

Comment: I know that, but you don't use this constraint - actually, you don't use `TIn` at all

Comment: I see what you mean. since I don't actually call a ```TIn new()``` anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my code again, the problem was that I had the `set` accessor to private on all string properties, which is why the `int` property was still coming through.